# Identifying the underlying dataset from the print statement

Tags: python

I am learning Python and wanted to identify the data structure from the display of print statement. I wrote the following code:

```
set1={1,2,3,3}
print set1
tup1=(1,2,3,3)
print tup1
list1=[1,2,3,3]
print list1
dict1={1:1,2:2,3:3,3:3}
print dict1
```

And the output is:

```
set([1, 2, 3])
(1, 2, 3, 3)
[1, 2, 3, 3]
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

From this I infer that set1 is a python set, tup1 is a python tuple, list1 is a python list and dict1 is a python dictionary.

Can we use this analogy in a generalized way to identify the underlying data structure from the print statement?

Comment: you can use `type(set1)` or other variables name you mentioned above to get type of datastructure.. `type()` is built in function

Comment: `print(set1.__class__.__name__)`

Comment: Yes this works fine. Thanks for the hint...

Comment: This 'identification' would be visual or you want to read it from an application/script? If the latter, then I don't see any use on that, you'd better use the type that best fits for your application no matter what the original type was, don't you think?

Comment: I am learning to read python code and wanted to know the easiest way to find the return of a method without looking into the method. I tested both the commands "type(set1)" and "print(set1.__class__.__name__)". Both are working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the output of the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr). It is up to the object itself to provide a meaningful [`object.__repr__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__); the built-in types produce valid Python syntax that'll let you reproduce the same value, but for Python classes the `repr()` output is not always as helpful:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, bar):
...         self.bar = bar
...
>>> print Foo(42)
<__main__.Foo object at 0x102312990>
```

This only tells you what type of instance you have, not how reproduce the same value.

If all you want to know is the *type*, use the [`type()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

```
>>> type(Foo(42))
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> type({1, 2, 3})
<type 'set'>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use one of the below statements to find the type of a variable:

```
print type(set1)
print(set1.__class__.__name__)
```

Thanks to Virendrao and Padraic Cunningham for providing the answer